# Multicast stopping after a few seconds in promiscuous mode

Tags: networking, 18.04, server

I have a system that receives a very large amount of multicast data on its own network (it is the only traffic on the line). This data comes in on many IPs and ports. Normally someone would just have to connect to one or more, but for this system I need to read from all of them. Other systems we use also do this by using PCAP and Promiscuous mode. While developing this system it began losing it's multicast after a bit of time (between 15s and 60s).

So I started trying to figure out what is wrong. First I removed the chance my programming is at fault and began testing it with tshark. tshark sees the exactly what my software was seeing. The actions I used are:

```
$sudo ifconfig eno2 down
$sudo ifconfig eno2 up
$sudo tshark -i eno2
```

I then receive my multicast for a period and then it stops. Once its stops it gone for good until I take the NIC down and up again. This is repeatable over and over.

My ifconfig on eno2 is:

```
eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> MTU 1500
        inet 127.1.1.65 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 127.1.1.255
        inet6 fe80::ae1f:6bff:febc:1d05  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  txqueuelen 1000    (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1984750  bytes 420457182 (420.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 95  bytes 7418 (7.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Edited out the MAC Address. I have tried setting ALLMULTI and PROMISC flags but they made no difference.

So from what I can tell it seems like something is actively blocking the multicast after a period of time. Does anyone know why this is happening? Any proposed solutions? I'm not sure its my configurations or maybe an issue with the switch.

Comment: [127.0.0.0/8 is reserved space for loopback](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6890). Do not use that for non-loopback-purposes. This may introduce all kinds of weirdness.

Comment: I've changed my IP to 169.254.254.64/16 problem still persists.

Comment: Within 5 minutes of the problem, `sudo journalctl --since="-10 minutes"` will show you log messages including log messages about your problem.

Comment: Ran journalctl shows nothing. Just shows a promiscuous mode started and a promiscuous mode ended that corresponds with me start tshark and me ending tshark.

Comment: Read `man tshark` and use the`-p` option.

Comment: -p turns off premisc mode. That is the opposite of what I'm looking to do.